# What should I do if I'm confused in a small space?

Tags: brogue

In my best game of Brogue so far, I picked up Ifrit from an orb. On depth 16, everything is going well - Ifrit and a centaur, and decent equipment.

[image: Depth 16, with an Ifrit, in a small corridor.]

[image: My equipment.]

But suddenly, disaster: My centaur triggers a confusion trap.

[image: Two turns later, confusion trap triggered.]

In the small hallway, the gas is dense and no one can get away. Worse, a wraith walks in too. They just keep hitting it over and over, and I can't get to it to stand on it.

[image: Confusion gas everywhere, and pets and enemies just keep on triggering it.]

Eventually, Ifrit wandered off and while still confused, got sniped to death by three sentinels over a giant pit. I survived (barely) but met my end on the next level without my bro.

Given what I've got - notably, no healing, no teleport, and no fire - what's the optimal way to deal with this situation?

Comment: You can try to tunnel your way out if you have charges on that staff

Comment: @yx.x: That's actually what I tried, the one charge left wasn't enough to make a difference.

Comment: So frustrating. Brogue is a very well designed game, but the fact that you can get indefinitely trapped like that, for (almost) no fault of your own, is one of its few flaws.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Throw something on the trigger when your allies step off, or, if that's unfeasible, stumble around until you're standing on it and then wait.

You could also use your Staff of Obstruction to keep your allies off the trap.  That seems like one of the simplest options.

(Why do you have potions of Hallucination?  They do nothing useful.)

Comment: Good call on using the Staff of Obstruction. I hadn't thought of that and it's definitely the best option I see. (I didn't know the potions were useless at the time, I figured if I threw them I might confuse something else.)

Comment: Yeah, you can throw with 100% accuracy even when confused, right?